# mysql according to time interval query data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL table:

[image]

My requirements are,At a 30-minute time  interval query data,with no need for group by,This concept,For the first time encounter this kind of question,How can I achieve that effect,The interval between the last one and the next is 30 minutes

Comment: Don't post data is images.  Post it as text, and use the markdown in the editor to format it.

Comment: "My requirements are,At a 30-minute time interval query data,with no need for group by," Why no group by? Is this a homework or job interview question?

Comment: This is my homework

Comment: sorry,I will pay more attention next time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the other day think of answer:

```
      SELECT  FROM_
      UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.Time)- UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t.Time)%(15*60)) 
      AS timekey,DB33,Stream,`View`,Coil
      FROM (select DB33,Stream,`View`,Time,Coil from  running_check where    
     DB33=#{DB33} ORDER BY id desc  limit 10000)  as   t
      GROUP BY timekey
```

Comment: It's 15 minutes apart of interval

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select min(t2.time)
                from t t2
                where floor(to_seconds(t2.time) / (30 * 60)) = floor(to_seconds(t.time) / (30 * 60))
               );
```

Comment: hello,your suggestion  I adopted the,but Can't perform,isn't  sql syntax error ,All the time, no results

Comment: The intention is MySQL syntax.  There could be an issue with parentheses or something, but that would be a typo.